# How can I group the SwiftData @Query result by date Sections to display in a SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swift-data

I want to display a SwiftData Model in my List and have it grouped by month.  So each section will list the items with their date falling in that month.  An example would be like below:

```
@Model
final class Item {
    
    var name: String?
    var date: Date?
    
    init(name: String? = nil, date: Date? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Query var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        let groupedDuties = Dictionary(grouping: items) { (element) -> String in
            return element.date!.dateString()
        }
        List {
            ForEach(groupedDuties.sorted(by: { $0.key > $1.key }), id: \.key) { group in
                Section(header: Text(group)) {
                    ForEach(group.value, id: \.id) { item in
                        Text(item.name ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for a relatively small number of items.  But with several thousand items the list slows down significantly when initially loading and becomes unusable.  Is there another way to sort the data into groups without the performance hit?

Comment: If you are dealing with thousands of items it is best to use CoreData instead of SwiftData if you don’t you’ll have to implement lazy loading manually.

Comment: `@Query` can't do sections yet so you're probably best falling back to CoreData's `@SectionedFetchRequest` although that has its own issues.

Comment: @malhal thanks.  I was hoping to avoid that having just switched my entire app to SwiftData but I had no choice so went back and added CoreData again for the model that needed the grouped list.  It works well.  Only issue I'm seeing so far is that when I update and save an object, the changes are not shown in the list until I leave that view and come back again.  I can force it with a refreshID but prefer to avoid that.  Will work on resolving this issue.

Comment: @loremipsum thx.  reverted back to coreData rather than manually implement lazy.